# How can I add a photo from my Google Photos to the Google Image Search?

Tags: google-search, google-photos

How can I make a photo from my personal Google Photos available to the Google Image Search?

Comment: You have to make your photos public and make that the Googlebot index them. There are a lot of ways to do this, so I will vote to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Dear @Rubén, Vidar S. Ramdal has provided a great answer below.

Comment: I think that Vidar's answer is a good answer and I will upvote it, but I still think that the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use the image on a website in order for Google to index it.

From https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/175288?hl=en:

> If you'd like your photograph or image to appear in Google search results, you'll need to post the image on a website. If you don't own a website, here are some free content hosting services that you can use:
>
> - Upload your images to a social network like Google+
> - Add the images to a blog using Blogger
> - Create your own website using Google Sites

Google Photos is not mentioned as an option.

Comment: AFAIK, the list of free content hosting services in the quoted content doesn't pretend to be exhaustive. Even Google Photos is not mentioned, it could be used as it's able to provide a URL to access the photo. Maybe you would find useful too to checkout the related content in the Search Console Help like [Image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) :)

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. But I would find it strange if Google wouldn't mention its own service, Photos, if it were supported.

Comment: They didn' t mentioned the publishing features of the Google Docs editors either, by the other side, it's possible to share photos with Google+ directly from the Google Photos app :)

Comment: That makes for an interesting experiment! I have now submitted these 3 urls to Google for indexing:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P_MHU90bP7Pk7HThWBmuvhG9qRznpFsT0km5oskv82g/edit?usp=sharing (a Google Document)
https://goo.gl/photos/dVpCW71fFDUjxYtU7 (link directly to a Google Photo)
https://plus.google.com/+VidarSkaugeRamdal/posts/fJ7qhSMosGF (a Google+ Post)
They all contain the same image, and I have sprinkled some easily searchable keywords around them. I'll give it a few days and see if they can be found in Google Images.